# How to search for duplicates in an Enumerable list checking specific properties

Tags: c#, duplicates, enumerable

I have an Enumerable list of objects in it.

The object have the following properties:
-ID
-Name
-Type

I would like to collect the ID-s of those objects which have the same name and type in the list.

Answer (score 1):

To search for duplicates (based on two fields-`Name and Type`) in a collection and retrieve a thid field (`ID`), you need to begin by breaking the problems into parts.

1) Find Duplicates

- GroupBy key fields, (Name and Type)

`list.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Name,x.Type})`

- Filter Groups which has more than 1 elements

`list.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Name,x.Type}).Where(x=>x.Count()>1)`

2) Select IDs

- Flatten the groups

`list.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Name,x.Type})
    .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
    .SelectMany(x=>x.ToList())`

- Select IDs

  `list.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Name,x.Type})
                       .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                       .SelectMany(x=>x.ToList()).Select(x=>x.ID)`

Putting it all together, for example,

```
   var list = new List<CustomObject>
    {
        new CustomObject{ID=1, Name="Abc",Type="Type1"},
        new CustomObject{ID=2, Name="Def",Type="Type2"},
        new CustomObject{ID=3, Name="Abc",Type="Type1"},
        new CustomObject{ID=4, Name="Abc",Type="Type2"},
        new CustomObject{ID=5, Name="Def",Type="Type2"},
        new CustomObject{ID=6, Name="Def",Type="Type1"},
    };

    var result = list.GroupBy(x=>new{x.Name,x.Type})
                     .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                     .SelectMany(x=>x.ToList()).Select(x=>x.ID);
```

Output for above example

```
1 
3 
2 
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq and `group` to group all objects by name and type, then only taking ones with a Count > 1.

```
var group = from myObject o in myObjects
           group new { p.Name, p.Type } into grp
           select new { Name = grp.Key.Name, Type = grp.Key.Type, Count = grp.Count() };

var dups = group.Where(g=>g.Count >1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Linq `.GroupBy()` It will create a list of lists where each list is organized by a key.

`list.GroupBy(e => new { e.Name, e.Type })`

Comment: Why was this downrated?. I deleted now my answer, as is is using the same approach but maybe was too much in detail.

Comment: you only partially answered the question